# How do I specify multiple conditions in dplyr::mutate?

Tags: r, if-statement

I am cleaning a dataset on French parliamentary elections. I would like to create a new variable, called margin of victory (`mv`), that is as follows.

When the party came in first place (`rank=="1"`), I want `mv` to be the the difference between their voteshare (`voteshare`)  and the `voteshare` of the party than came in second (`rank=="2"`). When the party did not come in first, though, I would like `mv` to be the difference between the voteshare of this non-winning party (i.e., `rank==2:4`) and the `voteshare` of the party that did come in first (i.e., `rank=="1"`).

This is what I have tried so far, to no avail:

```
data<-data.frame(
  party=c("party 1","party 2","party 3","party 4"),
  voteshare=c(0,52,10,38),
  rank=c(4,1,3,2)
)
library(tidyverse)
data<-mutate(
  data,
  mv=ifelse(rank=="1",
            (voteshare-if(rank=="2"){voteshare}),
            (voteshare-if(rank=="1"){voteshare}))
)
```

The error it gives me, "`the condition has length > 1`", makes me believe that in the `else` part of the function it is trying to handle all of the non-winning parties at once instead of one at a time, by row. But even when I make the `else` part 0, I still get `NA` for winning parties (the `if` part).

This next code chunk obviously won't run, but just to be clear about what I am trying to do:

```
data<-mutate(
  data,
  mv=ifelse(the party won,
            (voteshare of this (winning) party - voteshare of the party that came in second),
            (voteshare of this (non-winning) party - voteshare of the party that won))
)
```

The data.frame output I am hoping for would thus be:

```
View(
data.frame(
  party=c("party 1","party 2","party 3","party 4"),
  voteshare=c(0,52,10,38),
  rank=c(4,1,3,2),
  mv=c(-52,14,-42,-14))
)
```

I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Perhaps my question is more about using multiple conditions in `ifelse()`. I have looked at other posts but it is not clear if they solve this particular problem. It feels so simple and I am rather adept at `R` so it's frustrating. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `case_when` does what you expect. Note that this only works when there's just one *rank* case `== 1` and `2`, respectively.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(mv = case_when(
                rank == 1 ~ voteshare[rank == 1] - voteshare[rank == 2], 
                rank != 1 ~ voteshare - voteshare[rank == 1]))
    party voteshare rank  mv
1 party 1         0    4 -52
2 party 2        52    1  14
3 party 3        10    3 -42
4 party 4        38    2 -14
```

Answer (score 0):

Another slightly different solution is to use `case_match` from `dplyr`. In this case, you can set a default formula that will be used when there is no match with any of the included conditions.

```
data %>% 
  mutate(mv = case_match(rank,
    1 ~ voteshare[rank == 1] - voteshare[rank == 2], 
    .default = voteshare - voteshare[rank == 1]))

#    party voteshare rank  mv
#1 party 1         0    4 -52
#2 party 2        52    1  14
#3 party 3        10    3 -42
#4 party 4        38    2 -14
```